# Issues unit testing controllerAs: logging controller returns a promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-controlleras

I'm trying to test a controller which uses the controllerAs syntax.  My problem is that when I try to test a function on the controller, I get "Expected undefined to be defined."

**Controller (shortened version)**

```
(function (angular) {
  'use strict';

  /* @ngInject */
  function PreflightCtrl($state, $window, $timeout, $stateParams, toastr, accountService, servicesService, geoService, visitService, localStorageService, Notifications, service, UTILS) {

    /* Exported Vars */
    var vm = this;

    /* Exported functions */
    vm.verifyDob = verifyDob;

    function verifyDob() {
      if (!vm.form.dob || (vm.form.dob.length !== 8 && vm.form.dob.length !== 10)){
        return;
      }
      if(vm.form.dob.length === 8){
        var lastTwoDigits = vm.form.dob.substr(vm.form.dob.length-2);
        if(lastTwoDigits === '19'){
          return;
        }
      }
      var dob = new Date(vm.form.dob);
      vm.verifyingDob = true;
      accountService.verifyDOB(dob)
        .success(function(data){
          vm.genderDisabled = false;
          vm.dobError = false;
          $timeout(function() {
            dobInput.blur();
          });
        })
        .error(function (status) {
          vm.genderDisabled = true;
          vm.dobError = true;
        })
        .finally(function () {
          vm.verifyingDob = false;
        });
    }
  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('PreflightCtrl', PreflightCtrl);

}(angular));
```

**Test**

```
describe('PreflightCtrl', function(){
  var PreflightCtrl, $state, $window, $timeout, $stateParams, toastr, accountService, servicesService, geoService, visitService, localStorageService, Notifications, service, UTILS, mockAccountService, mockServicesService;

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$state_, _$window_, _$timeout_, _$stateParams_, _toastr_, _accountService_, _servicesService_, _geoService_, _visitService_, _localStorageService_, _Notifications_, _UTILS_){

    //mock services used in PreflightCtrl
    mockAccountService = {
      verifyDOB: function verifyDOB(dob){
        return {
          success: function(callback){
            callback(dob);
          }
        }
      },
      isPermUser: function isPermUser(){
        return {
          success: function(callback){
            callback(true);
          }
        }
      },
      profile: {
        gender: 'male'
      }
    };

    mockServicesService = {
      isGenderAllowed: function isGenderAllowed(serviceCode, gender){
        return true;
      }
    }

    //prepare for dependency injection
    $state = _$state_;
    $window = _$window_;
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
    $stateParams = _$stateParams_;
    toastr = _toastr_;
    accountService = mockAccountService;
    servicesService = mockServicesService;
    geoService = _geoService_;
    visitService = _visitService_;
    localStorageService = _localStorageService_;
    Notifications = _Notifications_;
    service = {"id": 3, "code": "HL", "flags": {"multi_medicine": false}, "genders": ["male"], "name": "Hair Loss", "product": {"count": 3}, "visible": 1};
    UTILS = _UTILS_;

    //spy on the mocked services
    spyOn(accountService, 'verifyDOB').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(servicesService, 'isGenderAllowed').and.callThrough();

    //create the controller
    PreflightCtrl = $controller('PreflightCtrl', {
      $state: $state,
      $window: $window,
      $timeout: $timeout,
      $stateParams: $stateParams,
      toastr: toastr,
      accountService: accountService,
      servicesService: servicesService,
      geoService: geoService,
      visitService: visitService,
      localStorageService: localStorageService,
      Notifications: Notifications,
      service: service,
      UTILS: UTILS
    });

  }));

  it('should have a defined controller', function(){
    expect(PreflightCtrl).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should have a defined function called verifyDob', function(){
    console.log(PreflightCtrl);
    expect(PreflightCtrl.verifyDob).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should verify a DOB', function(){

    PreflightCtrl.form.dob = '01/01/1990';
    PreflightCtrl.verifyDob();
    expect(PreflightCtrl.verifyingDob).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

When I run the test, this is the output that I get:

Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) LOG: 'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.'

LOG: Promise{$$state: Object{status: 2, value: Error{message: ...}}}
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) PreflightCtrl should have a defined function called verifyDob FAILED
    Expected undefined to be defined.
        at /Users/tracy/Projects/LemonaidClinic/src/views/preflight/preflight.controller.spec.js:80
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) PreflightCtrl should verify a DOB FAILED
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'PreflightCtrl.form.dob = '01/01/1990'')
        at /Users/tracy/Projects/LemonaidClinic/src/views/preflight/preflight.controller.spec.js:85
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 15 of 15 (2 FAILED) (0.006 secs / 0.204 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Line 80 is this line: expect(PreflightCtrl.verifyDob).toBeDefined();

and line 85 is this: PreflightCtrl.form.dob = '01/01/1990';

and you can see the first line is the log of the controller, which returns a promise which means none of the functions or variables are on the controller that need to be there.

I'm also unsure why Angular is trying to load more than once, but it doesn't seem to be affecting any other tests.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the controller doesn't exist until after you call $rootScope.$apply(). Also, you don't need to manually inject every dependency. Angular will inject the ones it has if you're not customizing/overriding them in the test.

Comment: Where would I add $rootScope.$apply()?  The only dependencies I manually created were ones that were causing errors when I run the tests, and creating these mocked dependencies fixes those errors, so I assume they're necessary...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it more like this:

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new();

$controller('myController as vm', {$scope:scope, /*your dependency tree hell*/});
$rootScope.$apply();

vm = scope.vm;//This is your new controller, you can refer to it in tests.
```

I think the fact that you have to mock so much says your Controller has too many dependencies, directly and/or indirectly.

However, if you're not in a position to fix that, you can mock more easily by just creating a folder called "mocks" and dropping in files that have the same id as the real ones and pointing Karma to that folder. Those will override the actual dependencies. The downside is that you'll still have to do one-off mocks if you need something different than your registered mock, but it removes the task of having to set up mocks in each test.